# Ag grid dynamic cell flashing when grid updating without using cell renderers

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have been trying to implement cell flashing dynamically in my ag-grid angular project **without using any cell renderers**. I used only **value getters and value formatters** as I don't have any extra HTML elements to be included in the cells of the grid. However I need to show **green color** for the new updated values which are greater than the prev value and **red color** for the values which are smaller than the prev value when **flashing**. I have the enterprise ag-grid. The documentation for cell flashing : https://ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/flashing-cells. Is there any way I can accomplish this without using any cell renderer.